# I want two Flexsliders on the same page to run at different speeds

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to Flexslider.  I have two on one page, and they are running fine, but I would like to either change the "initDelay" of one or make them have different slideshowSpeeds, because it looks goofy that they both change at the exact same time.  Is there a way to do that?

```
 <div id="rightside">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
       <img src="images/1.jpg" />
     </li>
     <li>
       <img src="images/2.jpg" />
     </li>
     <li>
       <img src="images/3.jpg" />
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="rightsidebot">
  <div class="flexslider">
   <ul class="slides">
     <li>
       <img src="images/4.jpg" />
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="images/5.jpg" />
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="images/6.jpg" />
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reference to [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) scroll down and check its option, in there you can find `slideshowSpeed` and using that option you can set the flexslider speed.

**script:**

```
 $('#rightside .flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshowSpeed: 5000
      });

$('#rightsidebot .flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshowSpeed: 8000
      });
```